# Wrong georeferencing in raster exported form .ovr file

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing, bathymetry

I am working with a bathymetry that has been shared with me in .ovr format, when pulling to QGIS I realize that it has wrong coordinates, it is supposed to be at 20° latitude and it is at 0°.

I have tried to fix it with reprojection but it's still wrong. I need to transform this file to .xyz to be used in other software.

Comment: `.ovr` is the extension of overviews as a sidecar file. They are usually not georeferenced as the base file should be. So you should have `image.tif` and next to it `image.tif.ovr`. Are you missing the base file?

Comment: I just have another file with .tif.aux extension, it is a xml file and only has some details. I think I am missing my base file, so it is not possible to transform this .ovr in .tif and georreference someway?

Comment: The `ovr` is a tif already... but you have lost the georeference information. In case you know it, you can modify the tif file with `gdal_edit` or `gdal_translate`, setting the needed values. See that you have also lost the most detailed level of detail (the base file).